FormattedNumber from react-int1 library
I have problem, to format currency + value combination. with FormattedNumber method from react-int1 library
<FormattedNumber style="currency" currency="ZAR" value="120" />

I am using FormattedNumber from react-in1 library , and output is -> "R 100" with space between currenty and value . is there any way to remove this extra space ? or any other method from this library?

the code you show and the output you show don't match. Is there some typo there?
